# Вместо иконок Font-Awesome отображаются квадраты с цифрами

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, шрифты, fontawesome

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: на сайт подключил иконки Font-Awesome, но вместо самих иконок отображаются квадраты вот такого рода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл css подключен и в нем все шрифты подключены корректно (все пути верно указаны), в чем может быть проблема и как её исправить?
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Показывайте html. Скорее всего неправильно прописываете название классов.

Comment: Та же проблема, только в английской версии все иконки работают нормально, а в русской - отображаются такие же квадраты. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно правильно прописывать классы Font Awesome

для **v5**

```
<i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

для **v4**

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

Comment: Действительно, в прописке класса не было fa, только fa-icon. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что ваш css файл не может найти файлы иконок fontawesome. Скорее всего у вас неправильно указан путь в вашем css файле. 
То что показываются квадратики , указывает на то что ваш css файл успешно подключен, осталось только выбрать правильно путь до иконок.

Можете изобразить дерево вашего сайта(расположение файлов)?

Answer (score 0):

На днях я тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. И если у вас видны только квадратики, то это означает то что ваш css файл успешно подключен, но проблема в том что вы указываете на не правильный файл. И поэтому укажите на all.css или all.min.css(в зависимости от того какой вам нужен). И проверьте используете ли вы бесплатные иконки(если у вас нету подписки). Так же проблема может быть в не правильном написаний класса(лучше всего скопировать код на иконку с сайта и вставить).